# Display a specific Layout in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

is there any way to display a specific layout of a website in UIWebView? for example in www.google.com. can we display only Google image in UIWebView rather than showing all content of the  page like search bar , search button.. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It is not possible. When you call www.google.com on UIWebView you are displaying web page in your app. And you don't have any control on the content.

Comment: thanks, do we have any other method. do you know how can we make API for the websiter

Comment: @PradeepKumar : Im not sure if this is possible.